# Corner Cases to Verify Synchronous FIFO

Tags: synchronous, fifo

I'm trying to figure out the corner cases for verifying a synchronous FIFO during hardware verification.

My setup is a very simple two ports synchronous FIFO (write/read) and the write clk frequency is same as read clk frequency.

In order to test whether the FIFO overflow occurs or not, can somebody help me identify those corner cases so that we can completely verify this simple synchronous FIFO?

[image: synchronous FIFO Spec]

Comment: Is this a school assignment? Those are **not** the ports of a "simply" synchronous FIFO.

Comment: Thanks for your comments, odlfart. It is an interview question. It is simple to start, but very open question.

Comment: What does the "40 wr @100 clk" and "8 rd@20 clk" mean?

Comment: Hi Bruce, "40 wr @100 clk" means that it allows 40 write in 100 clk window. "8 rd@20 clk" means that it allows 8 read in 20 clk window.

Answer (score 1):

OK, that looks a bit more like a normal synchronous FIFO but:

- There is no FULL flag so the producer does not know when to stop writing.
- There is an overflow but no underflow (or rename this signal to e.g. error).
- There is no reset/clear. How does the overflow (error) get cleared?
- What is the depth? Lets assume N.

Test corner cases are:

- Writing to full FIFO check overflow gets set.
- Reading from empty FIFO  underflow/error???
- With a full FIFO do simultaneous write and read. overflow remains clear

Normal test cases are foreach x in 1..N

- Write X values and check empty flag is clear and stays clear after each write.
- Read X values and check empty flag is clear and stays clear unless it is the last read.
- In all case overflow should remain clear.
- Write always unique values and check the read values correspond.
- Toggle at least each data line high and low.

Always run with code coverage and check the score.

Comment: Nice! oldfart. As you point, a full flag is required to indicate FIFO internal state if the FIFO depth N < 40.  Let's say N=32, how are those corner cases? Also read window is 8 requests / 20 clk, the for loop can not loop from 1 ... N.

Comment: How to use the condition - 40 write request / 100 clk, 8 read request / 20 clk to generate the FIFO full/empty scenario?

Comment: You are completely missing the most inportant corner cases: Race conditions between the two clocks. Dual clock domain FIFOs are actually surprisingly complicated, and very difficult to verify fully.

Answer (score 0):

It may not apply for an interview question, but in the real world, I'd say use formal verification.

I had to do this once for real. A design proven in silicon wouldn't have worked at the clock frequencies requires foe the next product. We determined that the fifos had structural problems. I redesigned them and wanted to make sure I didn't break the design. Verified with random stimulus and some extra tests to hit corner cases and it looked good. But...

I then tried formally verifying that the outputs would be equivalent to the old design every cycle. In no time the formal tool found an input sequence where we had the empty fifo, filled it up, let it drain mostly, then did an odd sequence of reads with simultaneous writes, that caused the fifos to differ in their output. It was an 11 cycle trace and only a 4*entry fifo.

The moral is that for verifying something simple like a single fifo, formal verification is your friend.